# How to pass variable to bcp command within powershell script

Tags: sql-server, powershell, bcp

I am creating a string that I would like to pass to the bcp command from within a PowerShell script. Here is the code that creates the string

```
$fullFilePath = (pwd).path + "\$db.$table" + ".dat"
$copyExecString = "bcp $db.$table out $fullFilePath -E -N -Slocalhost"
```

I can paste the Write-host result of this into a command prompt and it runs just fine, but it won't work as follows:

```
$fullFilePath = (pwd).path + "\$db.$table" + ".dat"
$copyExecString = "$db.$table out $fullFilePath -E -N -Slocalhost"
bcp $copyExecString
```

I also tried using the ampersand character before calling the bcp command, but to no avail

Any ideas on how to achieve this functionality would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet to ensure that you parse what you want to execute prior to execution:

```
Invoke-Expression "bcp $copyExecString"
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a single string, tokenize it by splitting the arguments out by spaces:

```
& bcp $db.$table out $fullFilePath -E -N -Slocalhost
```

Comment: This works as well! Thank you very much. PowerShell scripting is very new to me, but I can see how useful it is after just a few days using ti

Comment: @TechDawg270 Glad this helped. You'll want to be careful of `Invoke-Expression` because it could execute something you weren't expecting. Check out [this Powershell team blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful.aspx) about it. You want to avoid it if you can. If you found this answered your quested please mark it as the accepted answer.